# Deriving the wave equation in 3 dimensions and the history of it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, math-history, wave-equation

I'm trying to find how the wave equation was derived in 3 dimensions.

Surprisingly, there isn't much information available on this apart from wikipedia of all places

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Scalar_wave_equation_in_three_space_dimensions

It mentions that Euler discovered it and a derivation is based on a solution to a spherical wave.

What I don't understand is where this information is from. If anyone knows a good source then please let me know.

The other 2 small questions I have concern the third equation underneath the relevant section which has the $$ f_{lm}(r) $$ expression.

What does l, m, r and the above expression represent in this case?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean derivation of the wave equation, or finding a solution to the wave equation? These are completely different stories.

Comment: Derivation mainly though the latter as well would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Then please specify your question.

Comment: How was the third dimensional wave equation derived?

Comment: What seems confusing to me is your reference to the spherical means. The spherical means point the way to the solution of the wave equation, and have nothing to do with its derivation.

Comment: Okay my apologies. It seems like I assumed it was a derivation. In that case, my questions relate to what I asked initially regarding what f_lm(r), l ,m and r mean in this case? Also if any sources are available to say how Euler discovered the 3 dimensional wave equation as I'm not having any luck trying to look for it.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by discovered the wave equation? Do you really mean "discovered the equation", or do you mean "discovered the solution"? I will try to answer your question, but not before you've clarified what you want to know.

Comment: It says on wiki "Euler discovered the wave equation in three space dimensions". My question is how did he do this? I got confused initially as I thought the info re spherical means was the derivation when it wasn't. My other questions are re the meaning of the variables outlined before. Thanks

Comment: Some answer can be found here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/11076/3462